# Problems in sequential order of execution

Tags: c++

I have some problems with the seqeuential order of my database requesters.

Given is the following example:

The Requester has a database connection, and an QueryBuilder, which is responsible for creating database queries.
These Queries can be executed by the Requester.

In order to support the escaping of the input parameters, the QueryBuilder needs a pointer to the database transaction.
This pointer will be set in the constructor.

The QueryBuilder is a member in class Requester, so we have to set the Transaction in the constructor of the Requester.
But at this time, the Database connection (+ transaction) isn't initialized yet (will  be initialized in method run()).

My problem appears in the code below:

```
class QueryBuilder
{

public:

    QueryBuilder(const DbTransaction* const dbTransaction)
        : _dbTransaction(dbTransaction)
    {
    }

    std::string QueryBuilder::getSelect(const std::string& key) const
    {
        return "SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE key = '" + dbTransaction->escape(key) + "';";
    }

private:

    const DbTransaction* const _dbTransaction;
}


class Requester
{

public:

    Requester()
        : _queryBuilder(_dbConnection->getTransaction())              // Here _dbConnection is not initialized
                                                                      // The -dbConnection->transaction pointer will be initialized in beginTransaction();
    {
    }

    ~Requester()
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        _dbConnection.openDatabase();
        _dbConnection.beginTransaction();

        // iterate over records and call for every record:
        importRecordByKey(key);

        _dbConnection.commitTransaction();
        _dbConnection.closeDatabase();
    }

    void importRecordByKey(const std::string& key)
    {
        DbResult result = _dbConnection.executeQuery(_queryBuilder.getSelect(key));
        // do something with result
    }
}

private:

    DbConnection _dbConnection;
    QueryBuilder _queryBuilder;
```

What is the best way to handle this problem?

My possible solutions would be:

1. Don't use the queryBuilder as an member, just create one in the run() method.
   But this is not good for the performance at all, because every record will create and destroy the QueryBuilder.
   For 100000+ Records this will cost some amount of time i would think?!

Example:

```
void importRecordByKey(const std::string& key)
{
  QueryBuilder qb(_dbConnection.getTransaction());
  DbResult result = _dbConnection.executeQuery(qb.getSelect(key));
  // do something with result
}
```

2. Use a pointer for the queryBuilder member. So i can initialize the query builder, after the dbconnection/transaction is created

Example (with a shared_ptr):

```
void importRecordByKey(const std::string& key)
{
  if(!_queryBuilder)
  {
    _queryBuilder(new QueryBuilder(_dbConnection.getTransaction()));
  }

  DbResult result = _dbConnection.executeQuery(_queryBuilder.getSelect(key));
  // do something with result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `importRecordByKey()` need to be public? If not, what about this?

```
class QueryBuilder
{
public:
    QueryBuilder(const DbTransaction* const dbTransaction)
        : _dbTransaction(dbTransaction)
    {
    }

    std::string QueryBuilder::getSelect(const std::string& key) const
    {
        return "SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE key = '" + dbTransaction->escape(key) + "';";
    }

private:
    const DbTransaction* const _dbTransaction;
}


class Requester
{
public:
    Requester()
    {
    }

    ~Requester()
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        _dbConnection.openDatabase();
        _dbConnection.beginTransaction();
        QueryBuilder qB(_dbConnection->getTransaction());

        // iterate over records and call for every record:
        importRecordByKey(key, qB);

        _dbConnection.commitTransaction();
        _dbConnection.closeDatabase();
    }

private:
    void importRecordByKey(const std::string& key, const QueryBuilder& qB)
    {
        DbResult result = _dbConnection.executeQuery(qB.getSelect(key));
        // do something with result
    }

    DbConnection _dbConnection;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if i have a lot of different queryBuilders? ... i don 't want to pass 5 or more of them. Maybe the Solution with the pointers is the best for that ?!